# ¿Por qué mi código no reconoce el atributo data-placement?

Tags: bootstrap-4, tooltip

Estoy pasando en estos momentos un curso de Bootstrap, en el trabajo con "tooltip" se me ha presentado un problema y es que por algún motivo el atributo data-placement='top' no me funciona. En el código de ejemplo debería mostrarme "Texto del tooltip" justo arriba del "Texto de ejemplo"

Este es un código de ejemplo:

```
<h5 class="card-title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Texto del tooltip"> Texto de ejemplo</h5>

    <script>
       $(function () {
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
       })
    </script>
```

De esta forma es que se ve en mi PC
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los archivos de bootstrap los cargo de manera local

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Por alguna razon no funciona con la etiqueta h5

Comment: ¿Es posible que tengas algún typo en tu código? El código que muestras funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

antes que nada no se si sea un error de programación o simplemente un error de dedo al copiar tu código, pero le hace falta un ";" al finalizar la linea javascript.

> $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

Por otro lado, probé tu código y funciona correctamente.

En el ejemplo que pongo abajo muestro dos textos, uno al inicio de la pagina y otro mas abajo, ambos muestran el tooltip, solo que el tooltip del primer texto siempre se va a mostrar abajo ya que no hay espacio para que este se muestre por encima del texto, no se si ese sea tu problema.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h5 class="card-title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Texto del tooltip"> Texto de ejemplo</h5>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h5 class="card-title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Texto del tooltip" style="width: 300px;"> Texto de ejemplo</h5>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: La `;` esta de mas.. es javascript... y el error que veo es que el tooltip se muestra al centro y el texto esta a la izquierda

Comment: Recuerda que para este ejemplo no esta definido un ancho en la etiqueta h5, y dado que por defecto abarca el total del ancho de la pagina, o su contenedor, el tooltip se muestra siempre al centro, ve de nuevo el segundo texto ahora que le he asignado una anchura de 300px

Comment: Me sigue sucediendo exactamente lo mismo que antes

Comment: @Jorge en que parte de tu código tienes el script que inicializa tus tooltips? Antes o después de importar las librerías Javascript?

Comment: @Arreguin92 Lo tengo inicializado después de importar las librerías javascript

Comment: @Jorge lo ultimo que se me ocurre es que cambies la forma de inicializar el tooltip y lo pongas dentro del bloque `$( document ).ready();` Ya he modificado el código de ejemplo para que veas como debería quedar.

Answer (score 0):

Después de tanto buscar, la respuesta es la siguiente:

```
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Había un error en la ruta hacia popper.min.js, se había omitido "/umd"